# How to update the values in Core Data with the updated values coming from the same API in Swift3

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I have a public API which returns the response like this:

```
{
    "messages": null,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 27,
            "key": "ABC",
            "value": "5",
            "description": "this is abc"
        },
        {
            "id": 28,
            "key": "DEF",
            "value": "1",
            "description": "THis is def"
        },
        {
            "id": 32,
            "key": "GHI",
            "value": "24",
            "description": "This is GHI"
        },
        {
            "id": 35,
            "key": "123",
            "value": "dd/MMM/yyyy",
            "description": "123"
        }]
 "status": 0
}
```

These values I am storing in the Core Data. Next when I am calling this API by passing the Time Stamp I will receive the Updated values for keys like:

```
{
    "messages": null,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 27,
            "key": "ABC",
            "value": "5",
            "description": "Hi all"
        },
        {
            "id": 28,
            "key": "DEF",
            "value": "1",
            "description": "I am here"
        }]
 "status": 0
}
```

So if you see the above response the keys whose values have been changed are displayed. So I need to update the core data with the updated values corresponding to the Key.

That means in my Core Data I need to update the values of ABC and DEF key.
**How is it possible in Swift3?**

The code which I used here for inserting datas:

```
func saveApplcationSettingsinCoredata(responseArray: [ApplicationSettingsDataResponse]) {
    for settingsObj in responseArray {
      if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let context = CoreDataHandler.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext
        if let applicationSettingsEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "ApplicationSettings", into: context) as? ApplicationSettings {
          applicationSettingsEntity.keyDescription = settingsObj.description
          applicationSettingsEntity.key = settingsObj.key
          applicationSettingsEntity.value = settingsObj.value
          do {
            try context.save()
          } catch let error {
            print(error)
          }

        } else {
          // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
      } else {
        let context = CoreDataHandler.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext
        if let applicationSettingsEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "ApplicationSettings", into: context) as? ApplicationSettings {
          applicationSettingsEntity.keyDescription = settingsObj.description
          applicationSettingsEntity.key = settingsObj.key
          applicationSettingsEntity.value = settingsObj.value
          do {
            try context.save()
          } catch let error {
            print(error)
          }

        } else {
          // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
      }
    }
  }

  func getSettingsDataFor(key: String) -> [ApplicationSettings] {
    var fetchedObjects: [ApplicationSettings] = []
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      do {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ApplicationSettings")
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "key == %@", key)
        try fetchedObjects = (context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [ApplicationSettings])!
      } catch {
      }
      return fetchedObjects
    } else {
      do {
        let context = managedObjectContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ApplicationSettings")
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "key == %@", key)
        try fetchedObjects = (context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [ApplicationSettings])!
      } catch {
      }
      return fetchedObjects
    }
  }
```

The code where I call this:

```
import UIKit

enum ApplicationSettingsKey {
  case ABC
  case DEF
  case GHI
  case JKL


  var key: String {
    switch self {
    case .ABC:
      return keyValue(key: "ABC")
    case .DEF:
      return keyValue(key: "DEF")
    case .GHI:
      return keyValue(key: "GHI")
    case .JKL:
      return keyValue(key: "JKL")
    }
  }
  func keyValue(key: String) -> String {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      let object = CoreDataHandler.sharedInstance.getSettingsDataFor(key: key)
      let value = object[0].value ?? "Printing default value. No value retrieved from db"
      return value
    } else {
      // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    return ""
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code how are you inserting first dictionary in the coredata?

Comment: @user1000 added the code

Comment: Please check my answer, if you need help please ask further questions